# PHP can't find dynamic library but it is on disk

Tags: php

I have to use a PHP extension called ssh2: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

I downloaded the sources, and compiled them. Then I copied the .dll to my php ext directory. Then I added `extension=php_ssh2.dll` to `php.ini` and I restarted Apache2 and I got the following error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ssh2.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found

It is weird because I have php_ssh2.dll on that path. Maybe I compiled it in a wrong way?

I am using xampp, by the way. The rest of the extension load correctly.

Comment: All of the extension requirements are fulfilled? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.requirements.php

Comment: OpenSSL yes, I don't know about that libssh2. It is a development library though, why should I need it? I can't find documentation in google on how to install it and integrate it with PHP

Comment: Is openSSL enabled? you can try installing libssh2 with PEAR

Comment: Yes, openSSL is enabled. I loaded the extension and it works correctly. I tried doing that install with libssh2 and it says 'No package found'

Comment: According to this topic: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10348416-RESOLVED-SSH2-not-loading-The-operating-system-cannot-run-1-in-Unknown-on-line-0 you should provide up-to-date ssleay32.dll to the  c:\windows\system32\, maybe it will help